# Change CodePane to Active Module Pane (VBE)

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I'm programming in the VBA Editor (extensibility) and creating a new module programmatically.  The new module is created without problem.  However, when the new module is created it opens up in the code pane as a blank module, which it is.  However, I want the active module (the one running the code which created the new module) to return to the code pane after the new one is created.  I don't know what the command would be to do that.  This is what I've tried so far.

```
Sub addNewStandardModule()

On Error Resume Next'   Adds Extensibility Reference for programming in the VBE
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", Major:=5, Minor:=3
On Error GoTo 0

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule


        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
        VBComp.name = "Module6"

        '  This is my attempt to return the active module to the active codepane, but it doesn't work
        With Application.VBE
             If Not .ActiveCodePane Is Nothing Then
                    Set .ActiveVBProject = .ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Parent.Collection.Parent
             End If
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered it myself.  Hope it may be useful for anyone else in the future.

```
Sub createNewCodeModuleAndReturnToThisOne()
Dim VBEProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim vbComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject


    Set VBEProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set vbComp = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    vbComp.name = "Module6"
    VBEProj.VBComponents("Module5").Activate
End Sub
```